# Выполнения порядка функций

Tags: python

Есть две функции:

```
def write_db(*args):
     пишем в базу

def main():
    логика
    write_db(1)
    return результат логики
```

Немного затупил! Когда из функции main() вызывается write_db(), main() будет ждать завершения write_db() и после этого сделает return или вызвала write_db() и дальше приступила?

Понятно тогда когда из функции write_db() нужно получить результат для дальнейших действий.

Answer (score 3):

Будет ждать. а main пока на паузе. Как только write_db завершиться, main продолжится. Поэтому write_db может смело возвращать результат, а main сможет его обработать. Так почти во всех языках программирования (ну кроме некоторых экзотических и некоторых функциональных).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос, собственно, не о Python`е конкретно, а о компиляции( трансляции ) текста высокоуровневого языка в низкоуровневый( например, в Assembler ). Что вообще такое функция с точки зрения ассемблера? Это перескок в определенный блок инструкций из текущего места, их выполнение и последующий прыжок обратно( только на 1 инструкцию вперед ). Этот прыжок обратно принято называть возвратом из функции. Что получается на самом деле? Если сильно огрубить( для большего понимания ), то тело функции( её код ) подставляется в то место, откуда она вызывалась. Далее этот код выполняется и затем продолжают выполняться инструкции следующие за вызовом функции. Таким образом создаётся иллюзия ожидания выполнения функции.

Кстати, [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) говорил о неких "экзотических" языках, где функции якобы выполняются параллельно с текущим кодом. Не знаю, что это..может, [[[[@KoVadim](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim)](/users/2739/kovadim) имел ввиду многопоточную среду выполнения.